# Create df column based on other columns in df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract, multiple-columns

Create len column based on  num_type_len by matching with num on two columns.

| num_type_len | Actual_num |
| --- | --- |
| [8812_CHECKING_90, 7094_SAVINGS_75, 9939_CHECKING_89] | 7094 |
| [6846_CHECKING_87, 1906_CHECKING_90] | 1906 |

Expected output:-

```
| Report_length | Actual_num |
| ------------- | ---------- |
| 75            | 7094       |
| 90            | 1906       |
```

Comment: What is `print (type(df['num_type_len'].iat[0]))` ?

Comment: type(df['num_type_len'].iat[0])----> list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare splitted values of lists by `Actual_num` converted to strings and get first match values by `next` with `iter` trick:

```
df['Report_length'] = [next(iter([z.split('_')[-1] 
                       for z in x if z.split('_')[0] == str(y)]), None) 
                       for x, y in zip(df['num_type_len'], df['Actual_num'])]

df = df[['Report_length','Actual_num']]
print (df)
  Report_length  Actual_num
0            75        7094
1            90        1906
```

Or use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with lists column with compare splitted values:

```
df1 = df.explode('num_type_len')

df2 = (df1['num_type_len'].str.split('_', expand=True)
                          .rename(columns={2:'Report_length'})
                          .assign(Actual_num = df1['Actual_num']))

df = df2.loc[df2[0].eq(df2['Actual_num'].astype(str)), ['Report_length', 'Actual_num']]
print (df)
  Report_length  Actual_num
0            75        7094
1            90        1906
```

Comment: I'm using python 2.7 version, can't use explode. Could you please provide another approach?

Comment: @Swetha - Can you test first solution?